# AS3 playing audio and looping it

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

I'm trying to get an audio file to play in the background of my project but so far have been unsuccessful so far. Heres what I've gotten so far.

```
package  {

    import flash.display.*; 
    import flash.events.*; 
    import flash.net.*; 
    import flash.media.*; 

    public class Music extends MovieClip {

        // Create a sound
        private var music:Sound;

        // Use a URLRequest for file path
        private var request:URLRequest;

        // Create a sound buffer
        private var buffer:SoundLoaderContext;

        // Create a sound channel
        private var channel:SoundChannel;

        public function Music() {
            // constructor code
            //Instantiate all sound objects
            buffer = new SoundLoaderContext(1000);
            request = new URLRequest("SMB3-Grassland-Map.mp3");
            music = new Sound(request, buffer);

            // Play music and assign it to a channel
            channel = music.play();

            // Add an event listener to the channel
            channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, loopMusic);
        }

        // playMusic method restarts music
        private function playMusic()
        {
            channel = music.play();
            channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, loopMusic);
        }

        // Channel event listener call playMusic method
        private function loopMusic(e:Event)
        {
            if (channel != null)
            {
                channel.removeEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, loopMusic);

                playMusic();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

this is just to play an external audio file and have it continually loop.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having an event listener that plays the sound again upon sound complete, you can add parameters to the `.play()` method. The first parameter indicates at what point in the sound you would like it to begin playing, the second parameter indicates how many times you would like it to play, and the third is used if you want to apply sound transform. In your case you can do `.play(0, int.MAX_VALUE);` this will give you the continuous loop you are looking for.

Comment: the problem is it's not playing anything at all

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? Are you calling the Music() function at some point?

Answer (score 0):

"the problem is it's not playing anything at all."

I copied your code and created an AS3 class file (substituting my own local MP3 URL)
Then created an AS3 file with the following:

```
import Music;
var mus:Music = new Music();
```

and ran it. The sound played and looped correctly.

It's working for me, so maybe that's why there are no errors. Sorry for the question but are your speakers on; is your system playing sound from another source... cd, mp3 player?

I've used the play(0, 1000); @Goose mentioned and it worked great; simple and effective.